# Pulling in data from MySQL and breaking it up between pages

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have working code that brings in data from my database as follows:

```
require("database.php");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuitem");

echo "<table width='1024' border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='5' align='center'>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Menu Items</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Add to Order</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'><img src=\"" . $row['picturepath'] . "\" /></td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['name'] . "</td> <td align='center'> <input type='button' value='More Info'; onclick=\"window.location='more_info.php?';\"> </td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['price'] . "</td> <td align='center'> <input type='button' value='Add to Order' onclick=''> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
```

However, the columns that I am calling have over 20 items. I want to limit the amount of items the page displays to 4 items per page, and then create multiple pages listing the remaining items in the database.

So far I have tried adding in the if then statement, but that didn't work very well. I'm not sure if that is even the correct way to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM menuitem LIMIT $startPositionVariable,$howManyItemsPerPageVariable
```

a separate query should determine how many total entries there are to begin with and determine how many pages accordingly.